# MySQL não criando a linha de conteudo PHP

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados, mysqli, phpmyadmin

Quando tento passar os valores para meu banco de dados eu não os encontro nele, estou usando php com MAMP.

Segue o código:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    $host = "localhost:8889";
    $user = "root";
    $pass = "root";
    $banco = "ArrayEnterprises";
    $conexao = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $banco) or die(mysqli_error());
    mysqli_select_db($conexao, $banco) or die(mysqli_error());

    $do = $_POST["env"];
    if($do == "Enviar") {
        $nome = $_POST["nome"];
        $email = $_POST["email"];
        $senha = $_POST["senha"];
        $img = $_POST["img"];
    } elseif($do == "Logar"){
        $email = $_POST["email"];
        $senha = $_POST["senha"];
    }

    echo "$nome    $email    $senha    $img";
    mysqli_query($conexao, "SELECT * FROM Usuario");
    $sql = mysqli_query($conexao, "INSERT INTO Usuario (nome, email, senha, img) VALUES('$nome', '$email', '$senha', '$img')");
    mysqli_close($conexao);
?>
```

Eu não sei ver muito as coisas no PhpMyAdmin, mas acredito que não esteja lá as informações que eu passei por parametro, o que pode estar errado?

Comment: Qual é o erro que aparece?

Comment: Alexandre, aqui a gente foca no problema; "galera", "obrigado", "por favor" é tudo ruido e atrapalha o entendimento da pergunta. Por favor, gaste um pouco mais de tempo formulando a pergunta, explicando o problema e explicitando os trechos de código que não funcionam. Tenho certeza que já te indicaram a [help] e o guia [ask] anteriormente...

Comment: Olá, Alexandre. Olhando seu código e sua pergunta não dá pra adivinhar nem qual é sua dúvida. Seria legal se você conseguisse [edit] a pergunta e explicar o que está tentando fazer, o que não saiu como esperado, e como é que você chegou a esta constatação. Se puder postar um [exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) também ajudaria. Ajude-nos a ajudar você.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Os problemas que aí estão, são básicos. Em recomendação, para começar a trabalhar com consultas à bancos de dados SQL, eu lhe recomendaria uma pesquisa sobre **CRUD**, acrónimo para:

- **CREATE** (INSERT)
- **READ** (SELECT)
- **UPDATE** (UPDATE)
- **DELETE** (DELETE)

São basicamente as 4 principais operações que se pode executar numa consulta SQL.

Como qualquer outro bom e "funcional" script que faça o uso de um banco de dados, deve-se primeiro criar uma conexão com esse banco de dados. No PHP a principal função responsável por isso é a `mysqli_connect` (procedural).

```
mysqli_connect('localhost', 'utilizador', 'senha', 'banco' [, outros])
```

O `host` padrão costuma a ser o `localhost`(Unix Socket) ou `127.0.0.1` (TCP/IP), e não há qualquer necessidade de especificar a porta, a menos que seja necessária.

Depois de establecer a conexão com o banco de dados, pode-se começar a ler, modificar, apagar, ou inserir valores no banco de dados.

## Create

```
<?php
$proced_con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'exemplo');

# @Create
# "INSERT INTO tabela (campos) VALUES (valores)";

$titulo = 'SóS';
$insert = "INSERT INTO exemplo (titulo) VALUES ('{$titulo}')";

if($query = mysqli_query($proced_con, $insert)){
    if(mysqli_affected_rows($proced_con) > 0){
        print "Inserido";
    }
} else {
    print "Não inserido @insert: " . mysqli_error($proced_con);
}

?>
```

## Read

```
<?php

$proced_con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'exemplo');

# @Read
# "SELECT campos | * FROM tabela [WHERE]";

$select = "SELECT titulo FROM exemplo";

if($query = mysqli_query($proced_con, $select)){
    while($resultados = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
        print $resultados['titulo'] . "<br/>";
    }
} else {
    print "Consulta não efectuada @select: " . mysqli_error($proced_con);
}

?>
```

## Update

```
<?php
$proced_con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'exemplo');

# @Update
# "UPDATE tabela SET [campos=valores] WHERE [campo=valor]";

$titulo = 'SóS';
$update = "UPDATE exemplo SET titulo='{$titulo}' WHERE id=117";

# @ Update
if($query = mysqli_query($proced_con, $update)){
    if(mysqli_affected_rows($proced_con) > 0){
        print "Campos actualizados";
    } else {
        print "Nada modificado";
    }
} else {
    print "Consulta não efectuada @update: " . mysqli_error($proced_con);
}

?>
```

## Delete

```
<?php
$proced_con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'exemplo');

# @Delete
# "DELETE FROM tabela WHERE [campo=valor]";

$delete = "DELETE FROM exemplo WHERE id=117";

# @Delete
if($query = mysqli_query($proced_con, $delete)){
    if(mysqli_affected_rows($proced_con) > 0){
        print "Removido";
    } else {
        print "Não foi removido";
    }
} else {
    print "Consulta não efectuada @delete: " . mysqli_error($proced_con);
}

?>
```

A fim de cada consulta, pode-se aliviar a memória utilizando `mysqli_free_result`, e deve-se também fechar a conexão com o banco de dados utilizando a função `mysqli_close`, depois de a consulta ter sido executada ou os terem sido valores retornados.

Estes são exemplos simples de um **CRUD** funcional, se quiseres saber mais sobre os comandos SQL, recomendo que visites o site da [oracle](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/), e para mais funções MySQLi, ou outras variadas do PHP, visita o site do [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php).

Agora focando o(s) problema(s) existente(s) no teu script, começo pela primeira linha, onde definiste confurações para o o ficheiro de configuração e os erros em sí.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

A menos que seja num ambiente de produção, esta configuração não compensa em nada, é sempre melhor fazer estas alterações directamente no `php.ini`, de modo a deixa-las permanentes e sem a necessidade de estar sempre a habilita-las no início de cada script.

```
$host = "localhost:8889";
$user = "root";
$pass = "root";
$banco = "ArrayEnterprises";
$conexao = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $banco) or die(mysqli_error());
mysqli_select_db($conexao, $banco) or die(mysqli_error());
```

Nesta parte, a configuração definida na variável `$conexao` já era suficiente, excepto o retorno para o caso desta conexão falhar. Onde tens `mysqli_error`, o correcto seria `mysqli_connect_error()`.

A função `mysqli_error` só é usada quando já se tem uma conexão com o banco de dados, e retorna apenas erros de funções `MySQLi`.

O uso de `mysqli_select_db` é desnecessário, uma vez que já se especificou o banco de dados na função `mysqli_connect` já não há necessidade de voltar a selecionar o banco de dados. Esta função é útil quando se quer efectuar uma consulta em bancos de dados diferentes sem ter de fechar a conexão, ou iniciar outra.

```
 $do = $_POST["env"];
    if($do == "Enviar") {
        $nome = $_POST["nome"];
        $email = $_POST["email"];
        $senha = $_POST["senha"];
        $img = $_POST["img"];
    } elseif($do == "Logar"){
        $email = $_POST["email"];
        $senha = $_POST["senha"];
    }
```

Ainda em tempos havia uma pergunta cuja principal dúvida era, a criação de novas variáveis para armazenar valores, havia muito boas respostas, podes encontrar esta pergunta procurando pela tag `php`. O que acontece é que quando se criam novas variáveis quando podemos simplesmente usar a variável de entrada, não fazemos praticamente nada de diferente, claro, além de perder tempo e aumentar mais linhas de código ao nosso script, e foi exatamente isto que aconteceu com a variável `$_POST` no teu script. Não há problemas em deixar esta parte como está, mas criar uma variável aí não foi preoveitoso de forma alguma.

Outro problema é saber se `$_POST['img']` é um campo do tipo `text` ou `file`, porque se for do tipo `file`, correcto seria usar `$_FILES['img']` em vez de `$_POST`. A variável `$_FILES` é normalmente uma array contendo todos os detalhes do ficheiro selecionado.

```
    mysqli_query($conexao, "SELECT * FROM Usuario");
```

A função `mysqli_query` retorna um objecto contento o resultado dessa consulta, para consultas como `SELECT`, `SHOW`, `DESCRIBE`, `EXPLAIN` executadas sem erros, por isso, deve ser normalmente atribuído à uma variável, para que possamos o resultado dessa consulta.

Acho que é tudo que havia para dizer acerca da tua pergunta, se continuares com dúvidas, e o que acabei de responder não for esclarecedor o suficiente, utiliza a barra de busca do site, e procura por perguntas com problemas semelhantes.

Comment: Cara muito obrigado de verdade, tanto pela disponibilidade de escrever oq escreveu quanto pelo fato de ter funcionado o que me disse.